# AVCaptureSession - add multiple outputs in parallel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapturemoviefileoutput, avcapturevideodataoutput

I'm trying to record captured frames as video while performing image processing tasks on the frames at the same time in parallel.

I have a single AVCaptureSession which I have added two separate outputs to -

1. AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
2. AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

I confirmed to both **AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate** and **AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate**

I am using `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` 
    for frame capture and analyze
    and `func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didStartRecordingTo fileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection])` for video recording

For some reason, each method works separately, but when I'm adding both outputs, only the video recording works and the "captureOutput" function is not being called at all.

Any thoughts why this is happening, what am I doing wrong? or what should I make sure while setting up and configuring the session?

Comment: These two(`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`) will not work with each other. Please explain your actual requirement so that we can offer alternate work around.

Answer (score 2):

These two(`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`) will not work with each other. You can use `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` for getting the frame to analyse as well as recording. You can find sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/yusuke024/b5cd3909d9d7f9e919291491f6b381f0)

Comment: That's weird since I couldn't find any mentions of them being mutually exclusive on apple documentations. Thanks for the reference, I'll look into it

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any document where it is specifically mentioned

Answer (score -1):

You can use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVAssetWriter to realize what you need. And I have a demo in https://github.com/gwh111/CoreMLRecord

hope it help.

Comment: Code uses AssetWriter, and not AVCaptureMovieFileOutput